# Find non-matching tuples within a numpy ndarray of different shape

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, multidimensional-array, tuples

I have two 2D numpy nd.arrays, which look like this:

```
array([[(8.740896690597141, 8.876692713421095, 9.00851158974712, 9.145444068354191, 9.28408129961672, 9.426695633486075, 9.566468862997622, 9.70794682093236, 9.851129327791336, 9.990902871495557, 10.129539951526514, 10.265904353744476, 10.40454167736898, 10.543746833476504, 10.682951919430115, 10.823861548201764, 10.966476001036952, 11.10681734189823, 11.247727003018403, 11.389205061890092, 11.527842080908012, 11.668183544206574, 11.806820362768068, 11.94772988939585, 12.087503256187054, 12.226139931642832, 12.365345188462726, 12.501141069620031, 12.63580046285405, 12.7704603017515, 12.907392448778293, 13.040915592759664, 13.176711179228963, 13.31307531579448, 13.444325882558912, 13.576712518723577, 13.702849407037908, 13.834668107505598),
.......
(-1.7763376710569024e-15, -8.881688355284512e-16, -8.881688355284512e-16, -6.256959093984815e-45, -2.6645065065853547e-15, 8.881688355284512e-16, 1.7763376710569024e-15, -8.881688355284528e-16, -1.7763376710583362e-15, -8.881688367982712e-16, -6.976150340436319e-22, -8.884757285153119e-16, 1.667635949256822e-15, -2.445688419777969e-13, 0.001298687125012586, 0.0051947468116605, 0.011688217537574272, 0.02597380302395519, 0.0610384249844283, 0.11623284819571751, 0.21233632725859825, 0.3688290858006328, 0.5986981211575598, 0.8798660249474886, 1.1805150938825832, 1.4831127306517058, 1.7454516703850584, 1.9422065934803932, 2.0668840371446056, 2.147405298608788, 2.2077963194793107, 2.2558490058162874, 2.3019535171451637, 2.3487070647624013, 2.3961098331218684, 2.4415644758219766, 2.4837724552990386, 2.525330908842052)]]
```

a1 has a shape of (1, 56) and a2 (1, 38). Each of their columns, I believe is a tuple containing some values. So a1 has 56 and a2 has 38 tuples. Both a1 and a2 have `dtype('O')` and type `numpy.ndarray`

What I want to do is to compare the tuples of these two arrays, and preferably get another array in the shape (1, xx) or at least just another list containing those tuples which are NOT shared among them. How can I do that?
What I tried to do is

```
l1 = []
for i in a1:
    for j in a2:
        for ii in i:
            for jj in j:
                if ii != jj:
                    l1.append(ii)
```

But l1 ends up giving me a length of 2128, which should not be the case (`len(l1)` should return number of tuples inside the list), even though it looks like a list with tuples: `[(....), (....)]`. I am also pretty sure my implementation is incorrect.

Comment: you exemplary arrays are ill-formatted, please fix it
What is `a1.dype` and `a2.dtype`?

Comment: Just edited. is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
a1 = [(1.1, 1.15), (1.2, 1.15), (0.4, 1.15)]
a2 = [(2.1, 1.15), (2.2, 1.15), (0.4, 1.15)]

merged = []
merged += [(x) for x in a1 if x not in a2]
merged += [(x) for x in a2 if x not in a1]

print(merged)
# >>> [(1.1, 1.15), (1.2, 1.15), (2.1, 1.15), (2.2, 1.15)]
```

Comment: a1 and a2 are supposed to be nd.array, not lists.

Comment: The same code will work regardless. Arrays can be converted into sets. Arrays can be accessed with the `in` keyword. Arrays are can be iterated through with `for i in`

Comment: it gives me, `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: Hmmm. Try this solution maybe?